# Append a character at each beginning and end of line in a file using Java

Tags: java, text, append

can you help me with this problem.

I want to put some characters/text at every beginning and end of each line in my text file e.g.

```
Hi there
Welcome
```

to

```
sometext Hi there sometext
sometext Welcome sometext
```

Thanks

Comment: This is homework, right? What have you tried? We won't do your homework for you. BTW, there are plenty of tutorials about Java and the way to read and write text files. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html for example.

Comment: If you're in some unixish environment, sed(1) is the perfect tool to do such things. No need to write yet another program.

Answer (score 4):

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("newfile.txt"), true));

        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            bw.write("someText" + strLine + "someText");
            bw.newLine();

        }

        bw.close();
        in.close();
```

Comment: -1 : What's the use of the DataInputStream here? Why don't you close your streams in finally blocks? Do you think the OP will learn something by copy-pasting this snippet?

Comment: hmm yes your are right! i should consider this before asnwering in future, thanks for pointing

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator it = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.lineIterator(file);
try {
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    String line = it.nextLine();
    result.append("sometext ").append(line).append(" sometext\n")
  }
} finally {
  it.close();
}

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(outFile, result.toString());
```

Comment: +1 for using a StringBuilder. The OP should be aware that this performs better than repeated string operations due to the immutability of Strings (http://bit.ly/oqT8Xh).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java's `String.format` method.

When you read the textfile with, say, a [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)'s `ReadLine` method just call String.format on the line.