# Is it possible to append columns to a text file in java?

Tags: java, text, awk, append

Am aware that

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file_name, true);
```

allows appending rows to a file. Is there a way to append columns of data to a non-empty text file starting from the first row?

For e.g., file.txt contains:

```
Name    Address
ABC     OtherLand
```

Can we later modify file.txt to be:

```
Name   Address   PhoneNumber
ABC    OtherLand 3333333333
```

I've heard of the awk command in Unix. If there isn't a way to do this directly in the java programming language, would appreciate if someone could share code-bits on calling awk using java syscalls.

Thanks!

Comment: No. You would need to write a new file (reading the old one and adding new data to each line).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append a character at each beginning and end of line in a file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173361/append-a-character-at-each-beginning-and-end-of-line-in-a-file-using-java)

Comment: well, no one said yes or no explicitly in the other thread, and so I was left wondering...

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. There is no such option. You can always open a file to read, write or append content to it.

To achieve this, you will need to

1. Read each line of a file
2. Append the content to each line.
3. Write to a temporary file